# Воспроизведение Интернет радио в XCode Swift

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте!

Я начинающий программист в *xcode swift*. Подскажите пожалуйста, как воспроизвести аудио поток интернет радио? Если можно небольшой пример, буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: А если интернет радио не mp3? и будет ли этот код работать на Swift 4.0 и выше?

Comment: Радио не MP3, там используется потоковое аудио, в целом вам разницы нет в каком формате вещают они, в любом случае вы получаете аудио поток

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer).

```
var player = AVPlayer!
let url = "http://....mp3"
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player.rate = 1.0;
player.play()
```